# postgres not listening on docker bridge network

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

My ultimate goal is to set up a docker container with postgres using docker compose, and allow the other services to connect to the database using the default bridge network.

I've read dozens of articles/tutorials/posts that imply this should *just work*. I've broken things down into this simple compose file, but I'm not having any luck.

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    container_name: mediacms-db
    hostname: mediacms-db
    volumes:
      - ../postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: mediacms
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mediacms
      POSTGRES_DB: mediacms
      TZ: America/Detroit
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h db -d mediacms -U mediacms"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  pgadmin:
    image: chorss/docker-pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
```

Executing these commands

```
$ docker compose up -d

[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container mediacms-pgadmin-1  Running                                                                           0.0s
 ✔ Container mediacms-db         Running

$ docker network inspect mediacms_default

[
    {
        "Name": "mediacms_default",
        "Id": "ba695e23c27ec162d34929c1a8536555eaf9d1d1bb24177024cc8e246dc8ab2d",
        "Created": "2023-07-17T21:07:41.01080441-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.16.0/20",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.16.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "59e9ba7036684056c8d25f44db538806ceb16971954ca794c45853eb57083379": {
                "Name": "mediacms-pgadmin-1",
                "EndpointID": "fbc8bce72023d47425cba4ab7363a221461604e64c8c76c4f9c78eb854d4c6c2",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.3/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "82cabd4ce9b11623ed26152a28eb6c5c2f6a6cce24e4c9f127e19922a7d2eaf1": {
                "Name": "mediacms-db",
                "EndpointID": "88731337fd994ba940c8c0d62f2676063e90dd7e01e0f001766182eb9257d4cf",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:10:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.16.2/20",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "mediacms",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.19.1"
        }
    }
]
```

Attaching to the db container, I can execute the following command successfully

```
mediacms-db:/# psql -U mediacms
psql (15.2)
Type "help" for help.

mediacms=# SHOW listen_addresses;
 listen_addresses 
------------------
 *
(1 row)
```

I open up pgadmin in my browser, http://myhost:5050, and try to connect to the database using

```
hostname: mediacms-db
maintenance db: mediacms
user: mediacms
password: mediacms
```

But the connection times out with this message.

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Operation timed out
Is the server running on host "mediacms-db" (192.168.16.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried exposing the postgres port and connecting from the host with pgadmin, which works successfully. But everything I've read says I should be able to connect from the container without exposing the port on the host network. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are using `chorss/docker-pgadmin4`, a third-party image that [is no longer maintained](https://github.com/Chorss/docker-pgAdmin4).

The official pgadmin image -- linked from [the pgadmin web page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-container/) -- is [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4).

Using this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine
    container_name: mediacms-db
    hostname: mediacms-db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: mediacms
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mediacms
      POSTGRES_DB: mediacms
      TZ: America/Detroit
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -h db -d mediacms -U mediacms"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:7
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - 5050:80

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

If I connect to `http://localhost:5050` and then register a new server using:

```
hostname: mediacms-db
port    : 5432
database: mediacms
username: mediacms
password: mediacms
```

Everything works as expected.

---

Keep in mind that if your `../postgres_data` directory contains an existing database, the `POSTGRES_*` environment variables are ignored. They are used only when initially creating a database.

Comment: Switching the pgadmin image did allow me to connect successfully. However, I think the second piece of the problem was an incorrect assumption on how docker-compose creates the host names for the containers. Most of the articles I've read indicate the db should have a hostname of 'db' from the service name, but I found in practice that this was being aliased to something like 'foldername_db_1'. Deliberatly setting the hostname property removed that ambiguity for me.